# How to implement derived property using Combine?

Tags: swift, combine

I have an observable object with two properties

```
class Demo: ObservableObject {
  @Published var propertyA: Bool
  @Published var propertyB: Bool
}
```

Now I want to add a derived property "propertyC" that is "true" if both propertyA and propertyB are true.

I found similar questions with answers that didn't satisfy me. I'm looking for a solution that uses the Combine Framework and not a "didSet" method as my real world project computes the derived property from more than two other properties.

When I'm using the derived propertyC in a SwiftUI view it should trigger a refresh whenever propertyA or propertyB changes even if I don't use those in the view.

Comment: Linking the other answers and explaining why they don't satisfy you, and why you believe there is a better answer when it's been answered several times, would be a first step here. Currently this feels like a dupe. I've seen some of the answers you're likely describing, and they are likely the best answers that exist. If there were a trivial "just add this one thing" answer to this, it would have been answered that way before.

Comment: @RobNapier: there are several reasons: some don't use the Combine Framework which I explicitly requested. Others use the Combine Framework and old beta version that has a different syntax. The solution Asperi posted under my question is exactly what I was looking for: a clean solution.

Comment: Asperi's solution involves a lot of unjustified machinery, since `var propertyC: Bool { propertyA && propertyB }` solves the problem as described: “When I'm using the derived propertyC in a SwiftUI view it should trigger a refresh whenever propertyA or propertyB changes even if I don't use those in the view.”

Comment: @robmayoff: I agree but my example was just a simplified one to get the concept using the Combine Framework. The real world usage involves different operators. One question to your solution: does propertyC really trigger a refresh even when it's not marked as "published" and neither propertyA nor propertyB is used in the view?

Comment: Yes, it triggers a refresh because it calls the `propertyA` and `propertyB` getters, which call through to the `@Published` wrappers, which notify SwiftUI that those properties were accessed. So SwiftUI knows that a view that uses `propertyC` depends on `propertyA` and `propertyB`. My advice is that you use the simplest solution you can until you have evidence that you need something more complex.

Comment: @robmayoff: Thanks, I'm using this now in a couple of use cases. It works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is possible approach (tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2)

```
class Demo: ObservableObject {
    @Published var propertyA: Bool = false
    @Published var propertyB: Bool = false

    @Published var propertyC: Bool = false

    private var subscribers = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    init() {
        Publishers.CombineLatest(_propertyA.projectedValue, _propertyB.projectedValue)
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .map { $0 && $1 }
            .assign(to: \.propertyC, on: self)
            .store(in: &subscribers)
    }
}

// view for testing, works in Preview as well
struct FastDemoTest: View {
    @ObservedObject var demo = Demo()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Toggle A") { self.demo.propertyA.toggle() }
            Button("Toggle B") { self.demo.propertyB.toggle() }
            Divider()
            Text("Result of C: \( demo.propertyC ? "true" : "false" )")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think using a `CurrentValueSubject` would be a simpler approach. Could you try that? (I can't run Combine projects right now)

Comment: There is memory leak ... Once Demo is allocated, it will stay in memory "forever" (unless you remove all from subscribers), I suggest to use sink {[weak self] ... } or move subscribers out of Demo class

Answer (score 2):

All credits should go Rob (see his notes to this question)

```
class Demo: ObservableObject {
    @Published var propertyA: Bool = false
    @Published var propertyB: Bool = false
    var propertyC: Bool {
        propertyA && propertyB
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var demo = Demo()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Toggle A = \(demo.propertyA.description)") { self.demo.propertyA.toggle() }
            Button("Toggle B = \(demo.propertyB.description)") { self.demo.propertyB.toggle() }
            Divider()
            Text("Result of C: \(demo.propertyC.description)")
        }
    }
}
```